# NDK App Crashing After Uploading on Play Store

Tags: android, android-ndk

I uploaded an app to the playstore. The app contains native C code. I compiled it successfully using NDK, created the signed apk. I also installed the signed apk and checked. Everything worked fine.

After uploading it I downloaded it from playstore and it crashed.

Following is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1057)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2015)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load hello-jni: findLibrary returned null
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
at com.somepackage.anotherpackage.SomeActivity.<clinit>(SomeActivity.java:56)
... 15 more
```

The error states that System.loadLibrary returned null. But the same code when run using eclipse works fine.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? Did you try an older version to see if that worked?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your apk is missing libhello-jni.so. Maybe it was not packaged during apk build.

If you open your apk with a zip software, you should have a folder libs containing libhello-jni.so : if you don't have it, then you forgot something at build time.

Comment: I checked the signed apk and extracted it. It has libhello-jni.so. I don't understand how can the same code not execute if its uploaded to the playstore